# Advert showing some markup/not rendering correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

[image]

Running the latest version of Chrome, on a recent version of Windows.
Seems to only happen on Stack Overflow, not too sure about that though as the other sites don't seem to show that advert to me.

I'm pretty sure I don't have any Chrome extensions installed eg, ad blocker.

Only seems to happen with that advert.

Comment: posted also in [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357306/azure-ad-display-bug)

Comment: Cross-site dupe, more appropriate on MSO: I believe it's related to the size of the ad image, see [my answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357308/57475)

Comment: @Tanner ads are cross site, so this is better fit here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but OP says _Seems to only happen on Stack Overflow,_

Comment: @red "seems", but we can't expect people to go and try on all sites. When something is shared across more than one site and is bugged, this is the proper place. The per-site meta can also fit, but not only.

Comment: @redhand Not sure about that, I don’t get the advert on other sites for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch! This was due to an error in set up. When trying to append a click-macro we had a superfluous quotation mark in the creative tag.

Easy to fix, and a great reminder that our typos are visible by many!

Comment: Job well "done.